# How to responsive owl carousel in react js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, owl-carousel

I want to show only one item in mobile view. but it shows 4 item which i show in desktop view,
please help me out.

Here's my code:-

```
    <div className="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
      <OwlCarousel className="owl-theme hotel-slider tab-slide" id="tab-slider" loop margin={10} items={4} nav>
        {Data.shimladetail.map((shimlatour, i) => (

        <div className="item no-brdr">
          <img src={shimlatour.alltourimg} className="tour-img" />
          <div className="tour-cntnt">
            <h5 className="tours-heading">{shimlatour.alltourtitle}</h5>
            <p className="tour-pera">{shimlatour.alltourdiscription}</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        ))}
      </OwlCarousel>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to set this in JavaScript.

Comment: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/responsive.html

Comment: i'll add the java script,but the same issue show

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your JavaScript?

Comment: No i didn't edit my post after add the javaScript.

Comment: I know, that's what I'm asking you to do. Add your JavaScript to the post.

Comment: The issue is solved thanks for helping me..

Answer (score 1):

try to use plugin events please like `onResize` && `onResized`
 or options like `mergeFit` && `autoWidth` , you find this options in this link in below :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-owl-carousel